# Webcam showing image with circular artifacts

Tags: ubuntu, camera, amd-graphics

What could have caused the issue where the built-in webcam in my laptop captures a video stream with weird graphical artifacts?

These artifacts randomly appear or disappear for some period without any observed reason. Additionally, I cannot see the artifacts if the webcam cap is closed.

[image: A photo from webcam]

- Laptop: Lenovo ThinkPad T14s Gen 1;
- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS;
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 4750U with radeon graphics × 16
- GPU: AMD Renoir (renoir, LLVM 15.0.3, DRM 3.48, 5.19.0-41-generic);

What I have already attempted without any effect:

- reinstalled AMD drivers with `amdgpu-install`
- updated Linux kernels from 5.15 to 5.19.0-41-generic;
- updated Ubuntu firmware;
- switched graphics between Xorg and Wayland;
- replaced *cheese* with *guvcvview*;

UPD: connected USB Logitech webcam, working perfectly, without any glitches.

Comment: there's 28 different SKUs in the `AMD Renoir` range - can you please be more specific (and no-one refers to JUST the code name when describing their CPU)

Comment: what's the specifications of the camera?

Comment: Check on a PC with Windows.

Comment: Neither a camera nor a driver have anything inside to produce circular effects, not even by some damage or EMC problem. So it's either optics (extremely unlikely with those »digital« artefacts) or software effects applied without your knowledge, so please let me ask: Do you have any foes?

Comment: @JaromandaX updated the post with CPU / GPU info;

Comment: the camera is integrated into laptop as /dev/video0; here is some specs


[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x55afa68e2680] Compressed:       mjpeg :          Motion-JPEG : 1280x720 960x540 848x480 640x480 640x360 424x240 352x288 320x240 320x180
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x55afa68e2680] Raw       :     yuyv422 :           YUYV 4:2:2 : 1280x720 960x540 848x480 640x480 640x360 424x240 352x288 320x240 320x180

Comment: First guess is a hardware problem: Something wrong with the lens. Colored rings are typically for lens problems, as light of different color refracts differently, and the lens is rotation symmetric.

Comment: @dirkt I was also guessing about HW issues, however these rings may randomly appear or disappear in the similar conditions (lightning, period of the day, RAM usage etc)

Comment: @enoted then my guess is the lens housing is loose, and whenever you touch the camera (or depending on temperature), the lens slightly misadjusts. Rings are such a typical lens artifact, I don't see a way they could be creating by anything else.

Comment: Try to boot a Linux live image and see if that still happens